# How can i debugg my angular2 project

Tags: debugging, angular, typescript

I search for my ts files in console but it did not appeared.

I have been trying a lot for debugging my angular 2 project but no. Now I cannot go forward without debugging, can someone help me?

Comment: You could look at [Augury Tool](https://augury.angular.io/) its google dev tool extention

Answer (score 0):

In *tsconfig.json* file you should have
**"sourceMap": true**

When you put **debugger** command to your ts file browser stops to that point. This works at least in Chrome when you have developer tool visible (F12).

Comment: Done with that but still no use